# Play audio from byte array continuously

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming

```
let url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(data))
let audio = new Audio(url)
audio.play()
```

If I push data into array, audio doesn't continue. Actually, I'm going to stream audio from byte array.

Comment: What's in this byte array?  Raw PCM?  Or, compressed audio?  You probably want either the MediaSource Extensions or the new Web Codecs API.

Comment: @Brad MediaRecorder is pushing data into array